# How to save a plot (generated by shap_values) to png?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, save, png, shap

I use Shap  library to visualize variable importance.

I try to save shap_summary_plot as 'png' image  but my image.png but them get an empty image

this is the code that I have used:

```
shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(modelo).shap_values(X_train)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train, plot_type="bar")
plt.savefig('grafico.png')
```

The code worked but the image saved was empty.

How can I save the plot as image.png?

Answer (score 18):

I solved the problem. The code is:

```
shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(modelo).shap_values(X_train)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train, plot_type="bar",show=False)
plt.savefig('grafic.png')
```

Comment: Side note: make sure you clear/close previous figures if you make multiple plots. Otherwise in my case, they're all plotted overlapping each other.